# How to convert Material texbox to Yii2 textInput with template

Tags: yii2, textbox

> I want to convert this textbox to yii2, I have used template and also used inputTemplate but I didn't get the required result, any help is highly appreciated.

```
 <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="material-icons">person</i>
        </span>
       <div class="form-line">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        </div>
     </div>
```

> My yii2 code for this textbox

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'username')
                        ->textInput(
                        [ 'inputTemplate' => '<div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        </span> <div class="form-line">{input}{label}</div>{error}</div></div>']
                        ) ?>
```

> Required Result

[image: Required Result]

> Current Result

[image: current result]

Comment: May be `'inputTemplate' => 'div class="input-group">` missing **<** div opening messing up

Comment: I have added the missing < of div, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has `{label}` after `{input}`, the sample code of material hasn't label after input, So just remove `{label}` from your code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')
->textInput(
    [ 'inputTemplate' => '<div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                    </span> <div class="form-line">{input}</div>{error}</div></div>']
) ?>
```

Or set label of form to `false`

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')
->textInput(
    [ 'inputTemplate' => '<div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                    </span> <div class="form-line">{input}</div>{error}</div></div>']
)->label(false) ?>
```

Comment: Your wlc @AsifKhan , If is your answer then confirm it :);)